# How to show that $\sigma (X_n) \subset \sigma (X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Consider the random variable $X:(\Omega,F,\Bbb{P}) \to \Bbb{R}$

$$X_n(\omega)=n\mathbf 1_{F_n}(\omega)+\sum_{k=1}^{n2^n} \frac{k-1}{2^n} \mathbf1_{E_{n,k}} (\omega)$$
where
$$E_{n,k}=\left\{ \omega: \frac{k-1}{2^n} \le X(\omega) < \frac{k}{2^n} \right\},\,\, k=1,2,\dots,n2^n$$

and $F_n=\{ \omega:X(\omega) \ge n \}$.

In here, I'm bit confused about the fact that $\sigma (X_n) \subset \sigma (X)$. How can I show that ?

And how can we show that $X_n(\omega)$ converges to $X(\omega)$?

Comment: This follows  from the fact that $X_n=f_n(X)$ for some measurable function $f_n$ hence, for every $B$, $\{X_n\in B\}=\{X\in f_n^{-1}(B)\}\in\sigma(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a $\Sigma$-measurable set, then $\Bbb 1_{A}(\omega)$ is a $\Sigma$-measurable function, where $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Also, a random variable $X : \Omega \to \Bbb R$ is $\Sigma$-measurable if and only if for each $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R \cup \{ \pm \infty\}$, $\{ \omega : \alpha < X(\omega) < \beta\} \in \Sigma$.

These two facts should convince you that for each $n$, $X_{n}$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable.  This implies $\sigma(X_{n}) \subseteq \sigma(X)$.  If you have trouble filling in the details, let me know.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain your answer in detail?

Comment: @Oily Sure! But first I want to know what you've understood so far.  Are there any details you can fill in?  What does the solution (or partial solution) look like for you so far?

Comment: I understood the two facts you have given above. But I didn't get the answer....

Comment: @Oily The facts in my answer imply that the sets $E_{n,k}$ and $F_{n}$ are in $\sigma(X)$ for each fixed $n$ and $k$.  Do you agree with that?  That's really the only thing that needs to be understood.  Once you understand that, notice that the definition of $X_{n}$ is a finite sum of $\sigma(X)$-measurable functions, which makes it $\sigma(X)$-measurable, implying $\sigma(X_{n}) \subseteq \sigma(X)$.  So all you need to understand is why $F_{n}$ and $E_{n,k}$ are in $\sigma(X)$.  How do the facts in my answer show this? Hint: write down the definition of each set.

Comment: thank you! According to the definitions of $E_{n,k}$ & $F_{n}$ it follows right?

Comment: @Oily It should follow from their definitions.  But don't take my word for it.  Write the definitions out yourself and see.  If this is for a homework, it's entirely possible your instructor could ask you to explain your solution further, so you really need to understand it.  Take a few minutes and write down the definitions of $E_{n,k}$ and $F_{n}$ and justify to yourself why what I said in my answer implies they're measurable.  You should have a clear understanding for yourself why it's true.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me an idea to solve my second question?

Comment: @Oily Here's a hint that is basically the answer: Each $\omega$ is in $E_{n,k}$ for some $n$ and $k$ (why?).  Then $|X_{n}(\omega) - X(\omega)| \leq |\frac{k}{2^n} - \frac{k-1}{2^n}| = |\frac{1}{2^{n}}|$ (why?).  That's basically the main part of the proof, although you'll have to fill in the details like "Let $\epsilon > 0$,...".

Comment: I understand! Thanks!